# How does Google Dialogflow envrionments and version feature work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Google recently promoted the environments feature to GA. However, there are no APIs available to "promote" a Dialogflow agent from one environment (eg. staging) to another (eg. production).

I wanted to create a pipeline that migrates the bot. At this point, the only available solution looks like taking an export of the bot and pushing it to a new agent marked "production".

So, the question is, does Google internally take a zip and create a new agent for each environment we create? In doing so, will it maintain any training done on the agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your intention is to create multiple versions of your agent and publish them to separate environments; this way you would have custom environments for: testing, development, production, etc.

An agent version is an immutable snapshot of your agent. Therefore the training is expected to maintain between versions. However, in order to be able to serve different versions for different use cases you can select the environment in which you will proceed further trainings.

In order to publish an agent version and create new environments you can do it through the Dialogflow Console. You can also revert an environment to a previous version or load a previous version to draft. In [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions#publish_a_version_in_a_new_environment) you will find the in-depth explanation on how to achieve these actions.

Comment: Is this possible to do through an API? If not, would exporting a zip and importing that zip to another "instance" of the agent achieve the same?

Comment: Right now there isn't yet an API to set and manage environment versions. You can check the status in this Feature Request (https://issuetracker.google.com/153750593). Taking that into account, in the meantime you could try to export the agent as you stated in case you would like to do it programmatically. However, you might find inconsistencies between the ML model and the database state, as intent ids returned by the old ML model would not exist in the new agent. Therefore my recommmendation would be to use versioning feature, which was built to solve exactly such issues.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty important feature to be able to hook into CI/CD pipeline to run tests and all. But I am glad this issue is being tracked.